# How to fix the IETab extension work under Firefox 3.6?

Tags: windows, browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, firefox

I'm a happy user of Firefox, but I sometimes need to access sites using IE (at work, mainly).
Until now, I've used [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1419) which works fine... until you want to update to Firefox 3.6. The update program says it'll disable the add-on, and that's something I'd rather not do.

So, if there is no way to "hack"-update the add-on, do you know of an add-on with similar functionality?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Patience is a virtue! There's no absolute need to rush to 3.6

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2010/02/02/a-quick-and-dirty-way-to-update-your-firefox-extensions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The updated version is now called [Coral IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909)

Comment: Actually Coral IE Tab is not an updated version, it is a fork of IE Tab according to the extension site. ...since Coral is updated for FF 3.6 and IE Tab is not I run Coral now.

Comment: And while Coral IE Tab is good, there are some IE-specific sites which IE Tab tolerates, but it doesn't. Even just allowing IE Tab to be used by 3.6 would have been fine.

Answer (score 0):

if the only reason the extension doesn't work anymore is its embedded compatibility information (eg. it says "compatible with ff 3.0 - 3.5"), but not real incompatibilities (because of changed apis etc), you can use the [MR Tech Toolkit extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/421) to *disable addons compatibility checking* (options > miscellaneous > xpi install options). i'm successfully running quite some extensions which wouldn't work with ff 3.6 otherwise. don't know about ietab, though.